# Are there applications of interval graphs in musical analysis?

Tags: terminology, time-signatures, analysis

For each voice v_j we have notes n_ji (not rests) which are played at times s_ji and end at time e_ji. Now let us collet all intervals of time where the notes of all voices are played:
I_1 = [a_1,b_1],...,I_n = [a_n,b_n]. We can construct an undirected graph, which matches what can be heard:
I is connected to J iff I intersects J is not empty.
Hence two notes are connected if they share some time interval when they are played together.
Hence the listeners experience of listening some notes overlapped at the same time, is translated in graph theoretical terms to the [interval graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph) for further analysis.

My question is, if you know of research analysis in this direction for music?

Here is an example in Sagemath / Networkx:

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=jhqcyu

with correspoding graph image:
[image: interval_graph_for_music_analysis]

Edit:
Here is an example of "Una mattina" by Einaudi the interval graph:
[image: Consider for example a musical piece of v voices.]

Comment: I saw an article a few years ago that analyzed some music by dividing it into time slices and looking at which pitches were being sounded during each time slice.  I don't think they used a graph to identify the pitches, however (and in my own modeling I've yet to find a useful application for graph structures).  Unfortunately, I can't remember what the purpose of the analysis was, so I doubt I'll be able to find the paper, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: https://dmitri.mycpanel.princeton.edu/, Dmitri Tymoczko, _Geomoetry of Music_ may interest you. I don't know if he uses these graphs, but he does analysis with points in space for pitches.

Comment: (Oo—it would be fun to plan a performance in which such a graph was projected on a screen in real time as the piece progresses...)

Comment: Are you looking for interval graphs in general, or the specific interval graph in your question?

Comment: @Aaron: I am looking for the specific interval graph in my question applied to music.

Comment: Which journals have you checked so far?

Comment: @Aaron: I have googled for "music durations 'interval graphs' application" but no results. Maybe the terminology is different, which is why I have not found anything.

Comment: Try Google Scholar. Here's an initial search to get you started: [music analysis with "interval graph"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C48&q=music+analysis+with+%22interval+graph%22&btnG=).

Comment: Does this sort of analysis have applications?  Yes, I think so.  Do I know of any research along these lines?  No, but I'm not up on the current state of academic research.

This is basically the same type of analysis I once used on Ligeti's Etude 8 "Fem" to identify 'modulations' between 'key centres'.  IIRC, I did it on a per-bar basis, so not necessarily sounding together, and I didn't actually use a graph.  But it was basically the same idea.

Comment: It sounds like a fairly efficient structure if you want to check for some quality measure for different times. Like I saw a measure for dissonance somewhere if you store them this way it should be quite easy to traverse the song and find those parts. It would be cool to see the song represented as a graph over time with different qualities... but not sure if that's a real thing so to speak.